# Conexión FTP mediante Java

Tags: java, ftp

Buenos dias a todos, soy nuevo en FTP y mi servidor de internet me provee un dominio con un servidor FTP el cual quiero explotar porque me viene muy bien, mi idea es crear un aplicación en java que suba un archivo automáticamente al servidor lo cual no estoy logrando, logro exitosamente conectarme al servidor pero no el envió de datos.

```
package subiendo_archivo;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.InetAddress;
import org.apache.commons.net.ftp.FTP;
import org.apache.commons.net.ftp.FTPClient;
import org.apache.commons.net.ftp.FTPReply;

public class Subiendo_archivo {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        FTPClient client = new FTPClient();
        try{
            client.connect(InetAddress.getByName("staging.Carnicerialazaro1.arnetbiz.com.ar"),21);
            boolean login = client.login("user", "password");
            if (login){
                client.changeWorkingDirectory("/web/staging");//Cambiar directorio de trabajo
                System.out.println("Iniciando sesión Satisfactoriamente");
                int replay = client.getReplyCode();
                if (FTPReply.isPositiveCompletion(replay)){
                    File file = new File("D:\\Nuevo.txt");
                    FileInputStream input = new FileInputStream(file);
                    client.setFileType(FTP.BINARY_FILE_TYPE);
                    client.enterLocalActiveMode();
                    System.out.println("Subió satisfactoriamente el archivo");
                    if (!client.storeFile(file.getName(),input)){
                        System.out.println("Subida fallida!");
                    }
                    input.close();
                }
// Cuando cierras sesión el método logout regresa "true".
                boolean logout = client.logout();
                if (logout){
                    System.out.println("Salir del servidor FTP");
                }
            }else{
                System.out.println("Falló inciar sesión");
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        finally{
            try{
                client.disconnect();
            }
            catch (IOException e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }    
}
```

La respuesta es:

> Iniciando sesión Satisfactoriamente Subió satisfactoriamente el
>   archivo
>
> java.net.SocketException: Software caused connection abort: recv
>   failed    at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead0(Native Method)    at
>   java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:152)   at
>   java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:122)   at
>   sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.readBytes(StreamDecoder.java:283)    at
>   sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.implRead(StreamDecoder.java:325)     at
>   sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.read(StreamDecoder.java:177)     at
>   java.io.InputStreamReader.read(InputStreamReader.java:184)    at
>   java.io.BufferedReader.fill(BufferedReader.java:154)  at
>   java.io.BufferedReader.read(BufferedReader.java:175)  at
>   org.apache.commons.net.io.CRLFLineReader.readLine(CRLFLineReader.java:58)
>     at org.apache.commons.net.ftp.FTP.__getReply(FTP.java:313)  at
>   org.apache.commons.net.ftp.FTP.__getReply(FTP.java:292)   at
>   org.apache.commons.net.ftp.FTP.sendCommand(FTP.java:503)  at
>   org.apache.commons.net.ftp.FTP.sendCommand(FTP.java:628)  at
>   org.apache.commons.net.ftp.FTP.port(FTP.java:952)     at
>   org.apache.commons.net.ftp.FTPClient.*openDataConnection*(FTPClient.java:842)
>     at
>   org.apache.commons.net.ftp.FTPClient._storeFile(FTPClient.java:657)
>     at
>   org.apache.commons.net.ftp.FTPClient.__storeFile(FTPClient.java:643)
>     at
>   org.apache.commons.net.ftp.FTPClient.storeFile(FTPClient.java:2034)
>     at subiendo_archivo.Subiendo_archivo.main(Subiendo_archivo.java:28)

Answer (score 2):

Primero:

```
  client.changeWorkingDirectory("/web/staging");//Cambiar directorio de trabajo
  System.out.println("Iniciando sesión Satisfactoriamente");
  int replay = client.getReplyCode();
```

no se ve bien. Estás asumiendo que anduvo bien, pero

- no estás revisando lo que retorna `changeWorkingDirectory`
- estás imprimiendo el mensaje de todo bien antes de verificar el replycode, y
- si el replycode devuelve error no estas imprimiendo ningun mensaje de error - es decir, el check `if (FTPReply.isPositiveCompletion(replay))` no tiene `else`

Todo eso dificulta debuggear problemas.

En segundo lugar, no sé si estás al tanto de las diferencias entre [FTP en modo pasivo y activo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1699145/what-is-the-difference-between-active-and-passive-ftp). EL modo pasivo generalmente trae menos problemas de firewalls, te diría que pruebes eso.

Answer (score 2):

Yo tengo otra forma de organizar el código, hago métodos que hagan sub tareas... ya sabes, "Divide y vencerás", a parte, es mas fácil ver los errores. Total.

Te dejo la Clase FTP, la cual contiene los métodos que necesitas. (Es un resumen, pero para que puedas probarlo o comparar y ver en que falla tu código). Puedes añadir o quitar las líneas que no necesites... pero en cuanto lo leas, vas a entenderlo y está documentado y con comentarios, ello te ayuda a editar el código según tus necesidades.

```
package es.fips.ftp;

import java.io.*;    
import org.apache.commons.net.ftp.*;

/**
 * Clase que gestiona la conexión a un servidor y la de sus ficheros.
 * @author Fernando Pacheco Sánchez.
 *
 */
public class Ftp {
    // Variables de clase.
    private static String dirActual;
    private static FTPClient cliente = new FTPClient();

    // Métodos: 
    /**
     * Nos conecta a un servidor mediante usuario y contraseña.
     * @param server Servidor al que nos queremos conectar.
     * @param user Usuario para poder acceder.
     * @param pwd Contraseña para poder acceder.
     * @return True, si la conexión se estableció.<br>
     * False, es caso contrario.
     */
    public static boolean conectar(String server, String user, String pwd){     
        try {
            // Conectarse e identificarse.
            cliente.connect(server);
            if(cliente.login(user, pwd)){
                // Entrando a modo pasivo
                cliente.enterLocalPassiveMode();
                // Activar recibir/enviar cualquier tipo de archivo
                cliente.setFileType(FTP.BINARY_FILE_TYPE);

                // Obtener respuesta del servidor y acceder.
                int respuesta = cliente.getReplyCode();
                if (FTPReply.isPositiveCompletion(respuesta) == true) {
                    return true;
                }else{
                    return false;
                }
            }else{
                Util.msjError("Usuario o contraseña incorrectos.");
                e.printStackTrace();
                return false;
            }


        } catch (IOException e) {
            Util.msjError("Host del servidor incorrecto: "+server);
            e.printStackTrace();
            return false;
        }           
    }

    /**
     * Cierra sesión del usuario y se desconecta del servidor.
     * @return True, si se ha desconectado correctamente.<br>
     * False, en caso contrario.
     */
    public static boolean desconectar() {
        try {
            // Cerrar sesion y desconectar.
            cliente.logout();
            cliente.disconnect();
            return true;

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return false;
        }
    }

    /**
     * Cambia de directorio dentro de un servidor.
     * @param dirCarpeta Dirección completa de la carpeta a la cual queremos acceder
     * dentro del servidor.
     * @return True, si ha cambiado de directorio.<br>
     * False, en caso contrario.
     */ 
    public static boolean cambiarDirectorio(String dirCarpeta) {        
        try {
            // Ubicarse en directorio: ftp          
            cliente.changeWorkingDirectory(dirCarpeta);
            dirActual =  cliente.printWorkingDirectory();

            if(dirCarpeta.compareTo(dirActual) == 0){
                // Ha cambiado de forma satisfactoria.
                return true;
            }else{
                return false;
            }

        } catch (IOException e) {
            Util.msjError("Error al cambiar de directorio.");
            e.printStackTrace();
            return false;
        }       
    }

    /**
     * Descarga un fichero zip del servidor y lo almacena en una ruta específica.
     * @param nomFich Nombre del fichero zip a descargar.
     * @param destino Dirección donde se quiere almacenar el zip.
     * @return True, si la descarga y almacenamiento ha sido correcto.<br>
     * False, en caso contrario.
     */
    public static boolean descargaFichZip(String nomFich, String destino){
        String extZIP = ".ZIP";// El fichero de extensión que tu desees.
        OutputStream os;
        boolean fichDescargado = false;

        // Asegurarse que es ".ZIP".
        if(nomFich.length() < 4){
            return false;
        }       
        String extension = nomFich.substring(nomFich.length() - 4, nomFich.length());
        extension = extension.toUpperCase();

        if (extension.compareTo(extZIP) == 0) {
            try {
                // Descargar el ZIP. 
                os = new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(destino +"/"+ nomFich));
                fichDescargado = cliente.retrieveFile(nomFich, os);
                os.close();

            } catch (IOException e) {
                Util.msjError("No ha sido posible encontrar la carpeta: "+destino);
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        return fichDescargado;      
    }

    /**
     * Borra un fichero ZIP de la ubicación actual del servidor.
     * @param nomFich Nombre del fichero ZIP a borrar.
     * @return True, si se ha borrado del servidor.<br>
     * False, en caso contrario.
     */
    public static boolean borrarFicheroZip(String nomFich){
        boolean borrado = false;
        String extZIP = ".ZIP";// El fichero de extensión que tu desees.

        try {
            String extension = nomFich.substring(nomFich.length() - 4, nomFich.length());
            extension = extension.toUpperCase();
            if (extension.compareTo(extZIP) == 0) {
                // Borramos el zip.
                borrado = cliente.deleteFile(nomFich);
            }           

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return borrado;
    }

    /**
     * Sube un fichero al servidor en la ubicación actual.
     * @param pathFich Dirección del fichero, incluido el fichero. Ejm: /hola/queHay/pepe.txt
     * @param fich Nombre del fichero y su extensión. Ejm: pepe.txt
     * @return True, si ha subido de forma satisfactoria el fichero.<br>
     * False, en caso contrario.
     */
    public static boolean subirFichero(String pathFich, String fich){
        InputStream is;
        boolean fichSubido = false;

        try {           
            // Capturar el fichero de su ruta.
            is = new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(pathFich));

            // Subir el fichero en sí.
            fichSubido = cliente.storeFile(fich, is);           
            is.close();

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return fichSubido;
    }


    // Getters y setters:
    /**
     * Nos dice en que ubicación del servidor estamos actualmente.
     * @return Un String que contiene el path de ubicación actual.
     */
    public static String dameDirActual() {
        return dirActual;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Tu codigo es correcto. Acabo de probarlo con un servidor FileZilla en local y funciona bien. En tu caso, el problema està en la conexion de tu cliente con tu servidor FTP. Por alguna razon (firewall, permisos en el servidor) tu no puedes enviar datos al servidor. Ya probaste con un cliente FTP standard (navegador web, FileZilla, etc)

También puedes probar cambiando el tipo de transferencia: estàs enviando un archivo de texto pero especificaste una transferencia binaria. Intenta cambiar la linea :

```
client.setFileType(FTP.BINARY_FILE_TYPE);
```

por

```
client.setFileType(FTP.ASCII_FILE_TYPE);
```

Comment: Gracias por contestar, probe conectarme al servidor y subir archivos desde la MS-DOS de windows y, puedo subir los archivos tranquilamente y mas que lo que estoy haciendo no se hacer. Si podrias ayudarme

Comment: El tipo de transferencia influye en el resultado del envio. He editado mi respuesta.

Comment: Me sigue apareciendo el mismo mensaje de error. :(

Comment: Hice la conexion desde filezila  y tambien puedo subir los archivos sin error: respuesta de filezila "Estado: Conexión establecida, esperando el mensaje de bienvenida...
Estado: Servidor no seguro, no soporta FTP sobre TLS.
Estado: Server does not support non-ASCII characters.
Estado: Logged in
Estado: Comenzando la subida de D:\Nuevo.txt
Estado: Transferencia correcta, transferidos 0 bytes en 1 segundo
Estado: Retrieving directory listing of "/Web/staging"...
Estado: Directory listing of "/Web/staging" successful"

Comment: Si quieres puedo intentar conectarme a tu servidor y asi podré analizar mejor el problema. Enviame porfa un mail a merchanjavier@yahoo.com