# Estructurar conexion FTP usando modelo MVC en Java

Tags: java, mvc, aplicación-web, servlets, ftp

Mi intención es usar el modelo MVC que uso para la conexión en mi base de datos y aplicarlo a la conexion a mi servidor FTP,  primero les explico como me conecto a mi BD.

Este es la clase conexion perteneciente a la capa de Modelo

```
public class Conector {
public static Connection connect(){
String url="D:\\ANGELO\\Base de Datos SQLite\\SISGO\\sisgo.db";
Connection connect=null;
try {
    Class.forName("org.sqlite.JDBC");
    connect= DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlite:"+url);
    if (connect!=null) {
        System.out.println("Conectado");
    }
} catch (SQLException ex) {
    System.err.println("No se ha podido conectar a la base de datos\n"+ex.getMessage());
} catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
}
return connect;
}
```

Luego de eso esta es la conexión para hacer todo mi CRUD en las DTO_bo. Por ejemplo la siguiente linea de codigo agrega un usuario

```
public class Usuario_DTO_bo implements Usuario_DAO {
Connection con=null; //Creando la variable conexion para que sea usada por todos los metodos
@Override
//Metodo para agregar usuario
public void agregarUsuario(Usuario_DTO_bean usuario) {
    try {
        String salto=PasswordUtils.getSalt(30);
        String pass=PasswordUtils.generateSecurePassword(usuario.getClave(), salto);
        con=Conector.connect();
        PreparedStatement st= con.prepareStatement("insert into usuario (usuario,clave,permisos,estado,apellido_p,apellido_m,nombre,salto) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?);");
                st.setString(1, usuario.getUsuario());
                st.setString(2, pass);
                st.setString(3, usuario.getPermisos());
                st.setInt(4, usuario.getEstado());
                st.setString(5, usuario.getApellido_p());
                st.setString(6, usuario.getApellido_m());
                st.setString(7, usuario.getNombre());
                st.setString(8, salto);
                st.execute();
        con.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.err.println(e.getMessage());
    }
}
```

El codigo para agregar usuario no tiene importancia , la cuestion es que usando la linea

```
con=Conector.connect();
```

Puedo llamar facilmente a la conexion , y esto sirve para llamarla en cualquier clase, hasta ahí espero que entiendan como estructure mi llamada a la conexion.

---

LO IMPORTANTE

Ahora , encontré un codigo para conectarme a mi servidor FTP y funciona perfectamente , me manda los resultados por consola exitosamente.

```
package Database;

//aqui van muchas bibliotecas que no puse para no llenar espacio :)

public class prueba {

public static void main(String[] args) throws ClassNotFoundException, 
IOException  {

String server = "10.175.51.25";
    int port = 21;
    String user = "anonymous";
    String pass = "anonymous";
    FTPClient ftpClient = new FTPClient();
    try {
        ftpClient.connect(server, port);
        showServerReply(ftpClient);
        int replyCode = ftpClient.getReplyCode();
        if (!FTPReply.isPositiveCompletion(replyCode)) {
            System.out.println("Operation failed. Server reply code: " + replyCode);
            return;
        }
        boolean success = ftpClient.login(user, pass);
        showServerReply(ftpClient);
        if (!success) {
            System.out.println("Could not login to the server");
            return;
        } else {
            System.out.println("LOGGED IN SERVER");
        }

           ftpClient.logout();
           ftpClient.disconnect();


    } 

    catch (IOException ex) {
        System.out.println("Oops! Something wrong happened");
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }

}
private static void showServerReply(FTPClient ftpClient) {
    String[] replies = ftpClient.getReplyStrings();
    if (replies != null && replies.length > 0) {
        for (String aReply : replies) {
            System.out.println("SERVER: " + aReply);
        }
    }


}
}
```

El punto es que esto me funciona perfectamente en un main , la cuestion es poder estructurarlo para usarlo en MVC en web , y al igual como hice con la conexion a la base de datos poder invocar la conexion a mi FTP en una sola linea algo como

```
ftp=Conector_FTP.connect();
```

Comment: utilizas diferentes package para separar las capas?

Comment: @junior Si utilizo packages , uno es Modelo(ahi esta los DTO_bo), Controlador y otro Database(Ahi esta la conexion a la base de datos y tambien deberia estar la conexion al FTP)

Comment: mira esta forma de organizar la clase ftp https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/31741/96969

Comment: @junior la forma de ordenar la clase FTP es muy buena, probando en un main sirve de maravilla, ahora estoy que lo paso para que funcione con estructura MVC en web, cuando lo haga lo publico :)